# How do I use ExecuteNonQuery on a single line?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I currently have some code:

```
Dim InsertSecondCmd As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO [modules_access] (module_id, company_id) VALUES (5, " & intCompanyID & ")", thisConnection)
InsertSecondCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Can I tidy this up and have the whole thing on just one line of code somehow?

Eg.

```
ExecuteNonQuery(MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO [modules_access] (module_id, company_id) VALUES (5, " & intCompanyID & ")", thisConnection))
```

I tried a few variations but couldn't find one that worked. Advice welcomed!

Comment: Sure, make a function that runs the two lines and call it in a single line. You need to stop using string concat sql and start using parameterized statements. You could have serious sql injection vulnerabilities with this style of coding.

Comment: Hadn't thought of a function, this might be the answer!  Thanks for the injection heads up but intCompanyID is a value declared earlier in the code, it's safe, honest :)

Comment: In all honesty, if this came up in a code review in my office I wouldn't care where the value came from and would insist that it be fixed. This is not best practice, this is worst possible practice. @Michael Perrenoud's answer below looks really good.

Comment: You're right, change of plan, I'm going down the @MichaelPerrenoud route. Thanks for your help too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you could do this:

```
Dim affectedRows As Int32 InsertSecondCmd As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO [modules_access] (module_id, company_id) VALUES (5, " & intCompanyID & ")", thisConnection).ExecuteNonQuery()
```

But I'm not sure what benefit that is.

Finally, the number of problems with this approach are mounting. The connection and command aren't disposed properly, it's wide open for SQL injection, and it's barely readable.

For example, this is what your code **should** look like:

```
Using c As MySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(connString)
    c.Open();
    Using cmd As MySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO [module_access] (`module_id`, `company_id`) VALUES (@module_id, @company_id)", c)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@module_id", 5)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company_id", intCompanyID)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the paramatisation, interesting that you suggested even a static value be paramatised. The suggestion you made at the top of your post throws an error, "Keyword does not name a type." on the second Dim statement. I tried removing the "Dim affectedRows As" at the beginning but then the error changed to "End of statement expected." over the ExecuteNonQuery() part at the end.

Comment: Actually, ignore that, I'm bowing down to those far more experienced than I. It's a bit more code/work than I was expecting, but without doubt the correct way to do things. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Rich, I know what you mean. It's kind of like one bad apple ruins the whole bunch. We wouldn't have to worry about these things if there wasn't at least one bad apple out there. And the `using` statement, it's painful, but necessary. Though .NET has **some** automated memory management capabilities, it actually takes quite a bit of help to ensure that memory is managed properly. You're doing well, and be not weary in well doing my friend!